# Syntax error or access violation in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

When trying to run the following code,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO check (name, number) values ";
$query .= implode(',', $read_data); 
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

where `$read_data` is an array and has the value as `('aaa','000'),('bbb','001'),('ccc','002')`

I got an error as **Syntax error** or **access violation**

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check (name, number) values ('aaa','000'),('bbb','001' at line 1
```

Comment: Don't you get a *more complete* error message...?! What is the actual final `$query` you're sending?

Comment: `check` is a reserved keyword. Use backticks around it to disambiguate it as table name.

Comment: @zerkms query has the value for inserting multiple row by a single query like INSERT INTO check (name, number) values ('aa','001'),('bb','002');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$query = "INSERT INTO check ..."` to `` $query = "INSERT INTO `check` ..." ``. `CHECK` is a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

#### You do not have the proper syntax for your query:

This type of array would, but strings need to have single quotes and semicolon at the end.

```
$read_data = array("('aaa','000')","('bbb','001')","('ccc','002')");
$query = "INSERT INTO `check` (name, number) values ";
$query .= implode(',', $read_data).";";
echo $query;
```

Gives Me:

```
INSERT INTO `check` (name, number) values ('aaa','000'),('bbb','001'),('ccc','002');
```

Comment: thanks for your response and my mistake is i use check as the tablename which is reserved keyword